# how to set index variable in primeng p-table like in ngFor

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, p-table

Can any one assist me. I want to initialize index variable like
`*ngFor="let d of sI.detail;let i=index"`

In my p-table

````
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData >
      <tr class="text-center info">
        <td>{{ totalHeader }} </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            {{ rowData?.totalUnits }}
          </span>
          <span>
            ({{ rowData?.totalSale }})
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="rowData.totalUnits && rowData.totalSale">
            /{{ (rowData.totalUnits/rowData.totalSale) | percent:'1.2-2' }}
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>```
````

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `let-rowIndex="rowIndex"` property in your table. This will give you index of the row.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      <tr class="text-center info">
        <td>{{ totalHeader }} </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            {{ rowData?.totalUnits }} {{rowIndex + 1}} // here is value to use
          </span>
          <span>
            ({{ rowData?.totalSale }})
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="rowData.totalUnits && rowData.totalSale">
            /{{ (rowData.totalUnits/rowData.totalSale) | percent:'1.2-2' }}
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

Hope this help!