# How can I assign id to rows dynamically in table?

Tags: html, angular, html-table, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using p-table -> https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/dynamic
I want to assign unique id to each row dynamically.

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let i="index">
    <tr id=i>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Above code doesnt assign id to the row.

Comment: Maybe <tr id=“{{i}}”>?

Comment: Not working, tried that.

Comment: Wait, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819267/how-to-set-index-variable-in-primeng-p-table-like-in-ngfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
  <ng-template pTemplate="body"  let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <tr>
         <td>{{rowIndex}}</td>
        </tr>
</ng-template>
```

if you want to access it in your component you can use such thing

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

btw in order to see more examples, you can navigate to the primeng website:
https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table